# chain rule on trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$y=(g(\sin(3x)))^4$ and $g(0)= 3$ , $g'(0)=\frac{1}{9}$. We are supposed to find the derivative at $x=0$.

for $y'$ I tried and got 
$$y'=4(g(\sin(3x)))^3 \cdot ( g'(\sin(3x) + g(3\cos(3x))$$
What am I doing wrong? 
because right now if you plug in $x=1$ for $\cos(3x)$ you don't get$ 0$ and you need $0$ to get the $g(0)$

Comment: The line where you have ( g'sin3x + g3cos3x) is wrong. Replace it with ( g'sin3x * 3cos3x)

Comment: Did you mean $y = (g(\sin(3x)))^4$?

Comment: yes, sorry for the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y'=4(g(\sin(3x)))^3 \cdot g'(\sin(3x)) \cdot \cos(3x) \cdot 3 \\ = 12(g(\sin(3x)))^3 \cdot g'(\sin(3x)) \cdot \cos(3x)$$

So $$ y'(0) = 12(g(\sin(0)))^3 \cdot g'(\sin(0)) \cdot \cos(0) \\ = 12g(0)^3 \cdot g'(0) \cdot 1 \\ = 12(3^3) \cdot \frac{1}{9} \\ = 36$$

Comment: but would you use the product rule on whats inside the brackets?

Comment: No.  The expression $g(\sin(3x))$ means that the function $g$ is evaluated at $\sin(3x)$, so you must use the Chain Rule.

Comment: so the answer would be 36?

Comment: @user3467226 Well, you tell me :) Do you agree with my work? Is there any part of it that seems wrong?